# React and foundation: can't use row class

Tags: css, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use the foundation library in a ReactJs basic project. I installed the react-foundation and foundation-sites following this github project: https://github.com/digiaonline/react-foundation

Now the problem is i can't use the row class. Everywhere i go on the internet, in the foundation demos and documentation, i see the row class, but i have absolutely nothing for this clasd in my CSS. Instead of that, i have the grid-x, grid-y and other stuff. Is my foundation CSS incomplete?

Here's what i did exactly:

In my project i executed the commands `npm install react-foundation --save` and `npm install foundation-sites --save`. And in my index.js file i added this line `import 'foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css';`

In my app.js file, i have this code :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="row">
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But when i inspect the div in Google Chrome, there's absolutely no CSS for the row class. When i use grid-x instead, i have some style.

What am i missing?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You really need to show your code including how you are attempting to use the row class and how you setup react-foundation in your project.

Comment: Well i have absolutely nothing special. I have a basic ReactJs app, my web page html shows a div with a row class `<div class="row"></div>`. In my project i executed the commands `npm install react-foundation --save` and `npm install foundation-sites --save`. And in my index.js file i added this line `import 'foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css';`. That's it. When i inspect the div in Google Chrome, there's absolutely no CSS for the row class. When i use grid-x, i have some style. Is this the information you're asking? Thanks a lot

Comment: So you don’t use class in react, you use className, but there could be other issues like this that would help to have in the question, not the comments.

Comment: Ok i understant, i just updated the main description. Thank you

Comment: aren't you supposed to use `className="row"` instead of `class="row"` on the `div` ? like @AlexanderStaroselsky mentioned ?

Comment: It doesn't look like the newer version of foundation-sites even has the class `.row`, so this may be working as expected. There is a note on the Github page "Note: Newer versions of foundation-sites do not offer out of the box support for <Row/> and <Column/> components. If working with a newer version, <Grid/> and <Cell/> components should be used instead.". Also if you inspect the CSS of foundation-sites in dist/ there is no `.row` class. https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/develop/dist/css/foundation.css

Comment: Well i tried className, and stille no CSS related to the class row.

Comment: Oh okay, didn't know that row doesn't exist anymore, thanks a lot!

Comment: I've created an answer for the sake of closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [react-foundation](https://github.com/digiaonline/react-foundation) documentation, the CSS class `.row` no longer exists in new versions of the `foundation-sites` CSS. Therefore adding `className="row"`, will not have any effect whatsoever:

> Note: Newer versions of foundation-sites do not offer out of the box
>   support for  and  components. If working with a newer
>   version,  and  components should be used instead.

This can be confirmed by review the content of [dist/foundation.css](https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/develop/dist/css/foundation.css). Instead use components like `Grid` and/or `Cell` as specified in the documentation for react-foundation. Or you can obviously use classes [grid-x](https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/develop/dist/css/foundation.css#L861) that do exist in the foundation-sites CSS.

Also keep in mind, use `className` instead of `class` in React.

Comment: We still provide it but only in the float and flex grid css files.